# Adobe air log capturing tools?

Tags: logging, air

What is a good tool for capturing the logs from adobe air application? I'm looking for something that can capture the log from an air application when it runs (and ideally when it crashes).

I'm looking for something like Bugsplat (http://www.bugsplatsoftware.com/) for c/c++ as for adobe air/actionscript.

Thanks!

Comment: Checking this again since I come back to this problem again. Anyone can lend me a hand?

Answer (score 0):

[AS3 class that logs to a file in the File.applicationStorageDirectory](http://www.fmajakovskij.info/adobe-air-application-log-made-easy/)